# How to update the appearance of storyboards in split view controller after changing master column width

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm writing a split view (master-detail) iPad app using Xcode 10.2.1, and using the storyboard to do my layout.  I wanted the main column a bit thinner, so I went to the split view controller's panel in the storyboard and changed with width in its size inspector (in the right-side panel).  This works, but it doesn't update the child view controllers to reflect the new column size.  How do I made this change propagate to the rest of my panels in the storyboard?

Storyboard Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpTX7.jpg

Simulator Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O2Sy.jpg

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .This site is not a code-writing service. Try to solve the problem yourself, including researching your problem (e.g. reading notes, books, existing Stack Overflow questions, etc.), before asking a question. Afterwards, if you're still stuck, please feel free to ask a specific question; include a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of the problem and any errors you get in the question itself.

Comment: I'm not asking a coding question, this is more of an Xcode question.  The Storyboard is a graphical interface.  There's no code to post.  It's not throwing any errors.  I tried to post a screenshot but it won't let me because not enough reputation.  I've described the issue the best I can.  I don't know what else to tell you other than that I've looked all over Google and StackOverflow and couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Well after reading your question... I couldn't replicate what you are trying to achieve... and where you are having problem.. If you could share the configurations too as well would be helpful... The reason to share you more details was to make you understand the importance of detailed questions so we can replicate and efficiently help you to debug it.. By only providing a problem statement we can not help you in an efficient way...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I linked to screenshots (not sure why I didn't do that earlier, sometimes my brain doesn't fire on all cylinders).  You can see that the Root view controller in the storyboard has a narrower column, which is what I want.  However, the child view controllers in the storyboard don't reflect this change I made, so I don't get an accurate representation  of what it looks like when I'm doing my layout.  The actual app looks correct though.

Comment: Can you help me out with the issue that you are facing... I can see the screenshots but I could not figure out the issue that you are facing.. Sorry but I might not understand the problem correctly ... can you highlight parts which are not coming correctly? and what is supposed to be the correct layout? Sorry but I am lil' lost with the problem statement :P .. Which child view is not coming correctly? which are not updated?

Comment: In the leftmost panel in the storyboard, I shrank the left-side master view column to be narrower.  However, the child panels in the storyboard still display the left-side column as the default size.  When I run the app, it has the correct narrower column.  It's just a bit annoying during layout of the UI because it doesn't accurately reflect the final layout.